# encontrar el substring '&sa' dentro de un string con PHP

Tags: php, substring

tengo una cadena $k="http://biblioteca.usbbog.edu.co:8080/cgi-olib?infile=&sobj=5903&source=webvd&cgimime=text%2Fhtml&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwivtMb86OnrAhWwzjgGHQ_sAoQQFjAAegQIYhAB&usg=AOvVaw34bODURaeBFvJvJTgoKby_"

*necesito obtener parte del string antes de la primera ocurrencia '&sa'*

http://biblioteca.usbbog.edu.co:8080/cgi-olib?infile=&sobj=5903&source=webvd&cgimime=text%2Fhtml

**intento con la funcion de PHP**

```
strstr($k,'&sa',true);
```

el resultado es vacio pero si intento con

```
strstr($k,'&',true);
```

el resultado es : http://biblioteca.usbbog.edu.co:8080/cgi-olib?infile=

con que funcion o como podria obtener el valor esperado

Answer (score 1):

Para este caso en particular, puesto que estas hablando de URLs (la cadena es una URL con una query) puedes utilizar dos instrucciones que tiene php para ello:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-str.php

la primera te analiza la cadena y te devuelve un array con varios datos (el host, el puerto, el protocolo, la cadena de consulta, la uri...). Con ella extraes primero la query:

```
$query = parse_url($k, PHP_URL_QUERY);
```

ahora, dentro de $query tienes la cadena con los caracteres &. Aplica la otra funcion de php:

```
parse_str($query, $variables);
```

con esto, ahora $variables es un array asociativo, cuyas claves son la parte izquierda de lo que aparece en & y el valor asociado la parte derecha. Te devolverá algo como:

```
Array
(
    [infile] => 
    [sobj] => 5903
    [source] => webvd
    [cgimime] => text/html
    [sa] => U
    [ved] => 2ahUKEwivtMb86OnrAhWwzjgGHQ_sAoQQFjAAegQIYhAB
    [usg] => AOvVaw34bODURaeBFvJvJTgoKby_
)
```

solo te resta acceder al parametro que te interesa. En este caso, cgimime:

```
$cgimime = $variables['cgimime'];
```

un ejemplo completo:

```
$k="http://biblioteca.usbbog.edu.co:8080/cgi-olib?infile=&sobj=5903&source=webvd&cgimime=text%2Fhtml&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwivtMb86OnrAhWwzjgGHQ_sAoQQFjAAegQIYhAB&usg=AOvVaw34bODURaeBFvJvJTgoKby_";
$query = parse_url($k, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $variables);
print_r($variables);
```

Con estos ejemplos, puedes luego (con la informacion que tienes) volver a montar la url como te interesa.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo con la funcion [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) que crea un arreglo a partir de un delimitador

## ejemplo

```
$text = "http://biblioteca.usbbog.edu.co:8080/cgi-olib?infile=&sobj=5903&source=webvd&cgimime=text%2Fhtml&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwivtMb86OnrAhWwzjgGHQ_sAoQQFjAAegQIYhAB&usg=AOvVaw34bODURaeBFvJvJTgoKby_";
// creamos un arreglo delimitado por los caracteres "&sa"
// y obtenemos el primer resultado
$arr = explode("&sa",$text)[0];
echo $arr;
```

## resultado:

```
http://biblioteca.usbbog.edu.co:8080/cgi-olib?infile=&sobj=5903&source=webvd&cgimime=text%2Fhtml
```